# Password change plugin in poste.io fails

Tags: plugins, sqlite, roundcube

I am experiment with poste.io mail server.  It uses rouncube as its web interface.  I tried to enable the password plugin.

I see below error whenever I try to set the password:

> [21-Mar-2017 13:00:31 +0100]:  DB Error: [1] no such function: update_passwd (SQL Query: SELECT update_passwd('$1$LXeDlIT0$NGunS8gcCOSrKK2ZJ6RIW/', 'naidu@example.com')) in /opt/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_db.php on line 539 (POST /webmail/?_task=settings&_action=plugin.password-save)

The internet is full of using mysql as the database.  I think I have to update the password change query in

> /opt/www/webmail/plugins/password/config.inc.php

from

> $sql = 'SELECT update_passwd(%c, %u)';

to

> $sql = 'UPDATE mailaccount SET password=%c WHERE nname=%u LIMIT 1';

The UPDATE statement above is valid for mysql.  What is the equivalent for sqlite3 database?

Comment: Also posted the query here:  http://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php/topic,24177.0.html

Comment: Hi @BTR Naidu. Did you find a way to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

I have a setup consist of postfix with sqlite and my  sql query is as below:

```
UPDATE mailbox SET password=%c WHERE username=%u LIMIT 1
```

My sqlite config as below:

```
$config['password_db_dsn'] = 'sqlite:////var/vmail/postfixadmin.db?mode=0646';
$config['password_query'] = 'UPDATE mailbox SET password=%c WHERE username=%u LIMIT 1';
```

Add this for debugging:

```
$config['debug_level'] = 4;
$config['sql_debug'] = true;
$config['imap_debug'] = true;
$config['ldap_debug'] = true;
$config['smtp_debug'] = true;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using this same config but the only I get is a log entry with the query. The data doesn't change in the database. And the rouncube web interface shows error. Any ideas about what could be failing?